# Load the result of an egrep inside an editor (vim/emacs/gedit)

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I got some files, after an egrep command, like

```
egrep -l -r '(this|that|those)' *
```

This will list about 20 files. I don't want to open each one manually, is there any way to redirect the result from `grep`, directly to an editor so the editor will open those files to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
egrep -l 'pattern' * | xargs $EDITOR
```

`$EDITOR` should be set to your editor of choice, obviously.

OTOH said editor probably has a shorter, non-caps name, so you'd just type it directly.

Me, I'm all day doing this:

```
ack --ruby -l 'pattern' | xargs mate
```

(Also take the tip that `ack` is way cooler<sup>1</sup> than `egrep` and does recursive file matching by default, with filters per file type)

---

<sup>1</sup> Where by cooler I mean real `perl` regular expressions.